# threading error - too many args

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a python class in which I have a method I want to run a number of threads

```
class OutageTool:

def main(self):
    outages = [{
        'var1' : 1,
        'var2' : 2, 
    },
    {
        'var1' : 3,
        'var2' : 4, 
    }]
    for outage in outages:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.outage_thread, args=(outage)) 
            t.start()

def outage_thread(self, outage):
    """
    some code here
    """
```

When I run this code I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: outage_thread() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm new to python and would really appreciate any ideas on what's happening here.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten a `,` in your creation of `Thread`.

In python doing `(5)` will result in the integer `5`, while doing `(5,)` would turn into a **tuple** with one entry that is the integer `5`.

If you change your `args=(outage)` to `args=(outage,)` it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Make it

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.outage_thread, args=(outage,))
```

(Notice the , (command) after `outage`). In your case args is not a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error may lie in the fact that args=(outage) is not being considered a tuple.

This should fix it.

```
class OutageTool:

    def main(self):
        outages = [{
            'var1' : 1,
            'var2' : 2, 
        },
        {
            'var1' : 3,
            'var2' : 4, 
        }]
        for outage in outages:
                t = threading.Thread(target=self.outage_thread, args=(outage,)) 
                t.start()

def outage_thread(self, outage):
    """
    some code here
    """
```